# How to find out if an object supports a given interface (between two DLLs)

Tags: delphi, plugins, interface

I am just starting to get more familiar with how interfaces work so bear with me if this is a trivial question.

I have two plugins (call them A and B) in the form of DLLs (not packages). There is an interface with a GUID declared in application that loads the DLL, call it IMyInterface. Both plugins see the same interface definition with the same GUID. Plugin B actually implements the interface.

Plugin A wants to find out if plugin B supports the interface IMyInterface. I use obj.GetInterface (IMyInterface, IObj) to find this out:

```
var IObj : IMyInterface;
    obj : TObject;

obj := getPluginObjReference;

if obj.GetInterface(IMyInterface, IObj) then
   showmessage ('Interface Supported');
```

If I call this code within plugin B, the answer is yes, which is as expected. If I use the same code (cut and paste) in plugin A, the same code claims that plugin B does not support that interface. When I trace the GetInterface call into system.pas I find that InterfaceEntry := GetInterfaceEntry(IID); return nil, hence no interface to find.

For reference, IMyInterface looks like:

```
IMyInterface = interface
['{277A3122-A3F2-4A14-AE56-C99230F31CE9}']
   function getModel : AnsiString;
   function getDescription : AnsiString;
end;
```

and the implementation looks like:

```
// Now the real class, this is private to this plugin
TModelAPI = class (TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
   function getModel : AnsiString;
   function getDescription : AnsiString;
end;
```

etc.

My question:

As expected plugin B rightly claims that IMyInterface is supported. Why is it that Plugin A cannot discover that plugin B supports IMyInterface? Is there a problem with interrogating interfaces across DLL boundaries?

Comment: I am pleased to report that the answers given by ain and Heffernan provided the necessary information to solve the problem. I stopped passing objects and instead passed IInterface between the plugins, then I used the supports method to find out what interfaces were actually supported and this worked. I can now categorize plugins into what they reportedly can do. Many thanks for you help. The right answer goes to Heffernan because he gave a fuller answer but essentially both were right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot reliably pass objects across DLL boundaries. Instead you should pass interfaces across the boundary and use `as` or `Supports` to query capabilities. Interfaces are designed for binary compatibility across DLL boundaries, but objects are not.

You can readily pass an `IInterface` from one DLL to another and then query that. Or, if you have a common interface that all plugin objects implement, you could pass that. All that matters is that you always pass interfaces and never pass objects.

Comment: Not only does keeping "100% interface API" help your DLL work with Delphi without compiling both to work with runtime packages, it also works between various Delphi versions, and even between a DLL written in Delphi and an application not written in delphi. In short, Interfaces (COM) exists because of the need to write a specification (an Application Binary Interface) that won't change from release to release of a compiler, or between languages.

Answer (score 6):

You should really use only interfaces, ie the `getPluginObjReference` should return the lowest common interface supported by all the plugins and then you use [Supports()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.Supports) function to test what interfaces (plugin versions) that particular plugin supports.